# Shell script that copies while adding a user-provided filename suffix

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to write a shell script on Solaris that copies files from one directory to another. I need it to prompt the user for a date, and add that as a suffix to the destination filenames. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

src="/dir1"
dest="/dir2"

read -p "Date: " date

cp -Rp "${src%/}/" "${dest}"
find "${dest}" -type f -exec mv "{}" "{}_${date}" \;
```

`cp -Rp` copies the content of src/ recursively and keeps permissions

`${src%/}/"` makes sure that the source directory has a trailing /, because if it doesn't, cp -R copies the directory itself instead of it's content.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
Dir1="/dir1"
Dir2="/dir2"

read -p "Enter Date :- " Date

# if date is not set then use system date
[[ -z $Date ]] && Date=$(date +%F)

[[ -d "${Dir1}" ]] || { echo "ERROR: $Dir1 does not exists.."; exit; } && cd $Dir1

List=( * )

for File in "${List[@]}"
do
[[ -f $File ]] && cp -Rp $File ${Dir2}/`basename ${File}`_${Date};
done
```

Comment: “`-z STRING`      True if string is empty.” – So your logic is wrong, you set Date to current date if it already has value.

Comment: @manatwork please let me know your email id

Comment: You use find here to find all files in Dir1, also those in subdirectories, but you do not recreate the directory structure in Dir2, all files will end up in Dir2:

Comment: updated without find command